# Akka Actor custom Supervisors

Tags: akka, akka-supervision, akka-actor

Akka docs say to configure

> `akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy`, which takes the fully-qualified class-name of a `SupervisorStrategyConfigurator`

SupervisorStrategyConfigurator is a trait. Do I need to extend any classes with my subclassed trait? Or do I just define the trait and specify it in the configs, causing Akka to generate the guardian actor with that trait?

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy` is `"akka.actor.DefaultSupervisorStrategy"`(It is also default for any actor created without a specific supervisorStrategy). There are two known subclasses of `SupervisorStrategyConfigurator` (`DefaultSupervisorStrategy` and `StoppingSupervisorStrategy`). You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.1/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/FaultHandling.scala#L76).

If you want a custom one you need to extend `SupervisorStrategyConfigurator` and specify in the config file. An example for configuration:

```
akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy = "com.example.MySupervisorStrategy"
```